# Vuex State Not Updating Sibling Controls Completely

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I am having an issue with Vuex and updating of state to sibling components.  I am aware of the need for the `:key` binding and have it.

In my state I have:

```js
    filters: {
      clientId: 0,
      projectId: 0,
      projectRoleId: 0,
      subProjectId: 0,
    },
```

I have 4 components that make up this page:

**Month**: This component has child components but the v-for which has the filter is at this level

**DailyDetail**: This component shows a single days worth of time entries with more detail

**Agenda**: This is a vertical view of the same days shown in the calendar (Month control)

**Filters**: This is where we can filter on 1 of 4 fields (Client, Project, Sub Project or Project Role)

When I click and Add a filter, all 3 of the components (Month, DailyDetail and Agenda) all show the filtered results only.    This is what I want.
However, when I click the *Clear Filters* button on the Filters control, only the Month component seems to notice it.    The others just remain the same.  ASIDE from the fact that the `filtered` class is correctly applied and removed when the `hasFilters` getter changes.

If it helps, here are the Actions/Mutations and Getters in play:

The Setting of the filters goes straight to a Mutation from the computed setters:

```vue
    // Computed properties on the Filter component:
    filteredClientId: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.time.filters.clientId; },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('time/SET_FILTERED_CLIENT', value); },
    },
    filteredProjectId: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.time.filters.projectId; },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('time/SET_FILTERED_PROJECT', value); },
    },
    filteredProjectRoleId: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.time.filters.projectRoleId; },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('time/SET_FILTERED_PROJECT_ROLE', value); },
    },
    filteredSubProjectId: {
      get() { return this.$store.state.time.filters.subProjectId; },
      set(value) { this.$store.commit('time/SET_FILTERED_SUB_PROJECT', value); },
    },

    // Here are the corresponding mutations
    SET_FILTERED_CLIENT(state, value) {
      state.filters.clientId = value;
    },
    SET_FILTERED_PROJECT(state, value) {
      state.filters.projectId = value;
    },
    SET_FILTERED_PROJECT_ROLE(state, value) {
      state.filters.projectRoleId = value;
    },
    SET_FILTERED_SUB_PROJECT(state, value) {
      state.filters.subProjectId = value;
    },
```

Here is the Month component (this one Always works both setting and clearing of the filters):

```vue
    <template>

      <div class="month"
           :class="{ 'filtered': hasFilters }"
      >
        <weekDays />
        <week v-for="(week, index) in weeks"
              :key="index"
              :week="week"
        />
      </div>

    </template>

    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import week from './week.vue';
    import weekDays from './weekDays.vue';

    export default {
      components: {
        week,
        weekDays,
      },
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters('time', ['hasFilters', 'weeks']),
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Here is are the getters for these components:

```vue
    daysWithinPayPeriod: (state, getters) => {
      if (!state.currentDay) // This is simply to gracefully exit when no data is loaded yet
        return [];

      let payPeriodSerial = state.currentDay.PayPeriodSerial;

      // Find all of the entries within the pay period 
      let validDays = state.monthlyData.AllDays
        .filter(x => x.PayPeriodSerial === payPeriodSerial);

      if (getters.hasFilters) {
        for (let day of validDays) {
          day.ProjectTimes = day.ProjectTimes.filter(x => {
            return (
              x.Project.Client.ID === (state.filters.clientId === 0 ? x.Project.Client.ID : state.filters.clientId) &&
                x.Project.ID === (state.filters.projectId === 0 ? x.Project.ID : state.filters.projectId) &&
                x.ProjectRole.ID === (state.filters.projectRoleId === 0 ? x.ProjectRole.ID : state.filters.projectRoleId) &&
                x.SubProject.ID === (state.filters.subProjectId === 0 ? x.SubProject.ID : state.filters.subProjectId)
            );
          });
        }
      }

      return validDays;
    },
    hasFilters: state => {
      return state.filters.clientId !== 0 ||
        state.filters.projectId !== 0 ||
        state.filters.projectRoleId !== 0 ||
        state.filters.subProjectId !== 0;
    },
    weeks: (state, getters) => {
      if (getters.hasFilters) {
        let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.monthlyData.Weeks));

        for (let week of result) {
          for (let day of week.Days) {
            day.ProjectTimes = day.ProjectTimes.filter(x => {
              return (
                x.Project.Client.ID === (state.filters.clientId === 0 ? x.Project.Client.ID : state.filters.clientId) &&
                x.Project.ID === (state.filters.projectId === 0 ? x.Project.ID : state.filters.projectId) &&
                x.ProjectRole.ID === (state.filters.projectRoleId === 0 ? x.ProjectRole.ID : state.filters.projectRoleId) &&
                x.SubProject.ID === (state.filters.subProjectId === 0 ? x.SubProject.ID : state.filters.subProjectId)
              );
            });
          }
        }

        return result;
      } else {
        return state.monthlyData.Weeks
          ? state.monthlyData.Weeks
          : [];
      }
    },
```

Here is the Agenda component trimmed back a bit to show only useful info:

```vue
    <template>

      <div class="agenda">
        <table class="table table-hover mb-0 table-bordered"
                     :class="{ 'filtered': hasFilters }"
        >
          ...
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="day in daysWithinPayPeriod"
                    :key="day.DayOfYear"
                    :class="{ 'is-today': day.IsToday, 'weekend': day.IsWeekend, 'focused': isDaySelected(day) }"
                    class="day-row"
                    @click="selectDay(day)"
            >
              ...
              <td colspan="4"
                      class="breakout"
              >
                <table v-if="day.ProjectTimes.length > 0"
                             class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover table-borderless mb-0"
                >
                  <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="entry in day.ProjectTimes"
                            :key="entry.ID"
                    >
                    ...
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </template>
    <script>
    import { mapGetters, mapState } from 'vuex';
    import store from '../../store';

    export default {
      store: store,
      mixins: [ formattingFilters ],
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters('time', ['daysWithinPayPeriod', 'hasFilters']),
        ...mapState('time', {
        }),
      },
      methods: {
        selectDay(day) {
          this.$store.dispatch('time/dateSelected', day);
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

With the Agenda component, I would assume it is the nested `v-for` however the DailyDetail component (to follow) does not have a nested `v-for` and does not "clear" the filters.

Here is the DailyDetail component:

```vue
    <template>

      <div class="daily-detail">
        <table class="table table-sm table-striped table-hover mb-0"
                     :class="{ 'filtered': hasFilters }"
        >
          ...
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="entry of currentDaysTimeEntries"
                    :key="entry.ID"
                    :class="{ 'italic': entry.Project.IsUniversal }"
            >
              <td class="text-center"><i class="far fa-pencil" /></td>
              <td><div class="text-right">{{ entry.Time | formatNumber }}</div></td>
              <td>
                <div class="truncate">{{ entry.Project.Name }}</div>
                <div v-if="entry.SubProject.ID > 0"
                         class="subproject"
                >
                  {{ entry.SubProject.Name}}
                </div>
                <small>{{ entry.Project.Client.Name }}</small>
              </td>
              ...
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>

    </template>

    <script>
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
    import store from '../store';
    import formattingFilters from '../mixins/formatting';

    export default {
      store: store,
      computed: {
        ...mapGetters('time', ['currentDaysTotalTime', 'currentDaysTimeEntries', 'hasFilters', 'selectedDate']),
      },
    };
    </script>
```

The Clearing of the filters goes through an Action:

```vue
    // Action
    clearFilters(context) {
      context.commit('CLEAR_FILTERS');
    },

    // Mutation
    CLEAR_FILTERS(state) {
      state.filters.clientId = 0;
      state.filters.projectId = 0;
      state.filters.projectRoleId = 0;
      state.filters.subProjectId = 0;
    },
```

So to reiterate, the issue is that all 3 components use the `hasFilters` getter to apply a class called `filtered` over their component to signify that there are filters in play.  This part works for both setting and clearing of filters.  The problem is that the values that get filtered out when filters are in (that part works) do not get cleared out when the filters are cleared.  The Month component works perfectly, but the Agenda and DailyDetails just keep the filtered state.

Comment: The only thing I see is you are using `index` as the key for your Month component but you are using property attributes for the key on Agenda and DailyDetails. Have you tried changing the key to `index` on `v-for`'s in those two components?

Comment: @TJWeems Thanks for the response, I use the `index` because there is no unique ID and there are always 6 anyway.  However, that component works great.  The others not so much.  And `index` is not ideal as [this great article](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/) mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a good nights sleep I thought I would take another poke at it.  It was my fault (as expected.)  I noticed two things, one, the `DailyDetail` component showed the `filtered` class correctly (as mentioned above) however, it was *not* filtering the data.  So that fix was here:

**Original getter for `DailyDetail` that was not filtering**

```
currentDaysTimeEntries: state => {
  return state.currentDay
    ? state.currentDay.ProjectTimes
    : [];
},
```

**Fixed `DailyDetail` getter that does filtering**

```
currentDaysTimeEntries: (state, getters) => {
  if (state.currentDay) {
    if (getters.hasFilters) {
      return state.currentDay.ProjectTimes.filter(x => {
        return (
          x.Project.Client.ID === (state.filters.clientId === 0 ? x.Project.Client.ID : state.filters.clientId) &&
          x.Project.ID === (state.filters.projectId === 0 ? x.Project.ID : state.filters.projectId) &&
          x.ProjectRole.ID === (state.filters.projectRoleId === 0 ? x.ProjectRole.ID : state.filters.projectRoleId) &&
          x.SubProject.ID === (state.filters.subProjectId === 0 ? x.SubProject.ID : state.filters.subProjectId)
        );
      });
    } else {
      return state.currentDay.ProjectTimes;
    }
  } else {
    return [];
  }
},
```

Then, once that was fixed and 2 of the 3 components worked great I realized that the `Agenda` component (the one not working) wasn't *just* using the JavaScript `filter` method, it had to do a bit more and extract out what it did not need.

**ANSWER** It was `filter`ing the unwanted stuff out of the array overwriting the original array and thus when filtering was turned off, there was nothing to go back to.  So I made a copy of the array and all 3 work now!

**Original getter for Agenda that WAS filtering and also completely remove**

```
daysWithinPayPeriod: (state, getters) => {
  if (!state.currentDay)
    return [];

  let payPeriodSerial = state.currentDay.PayPeriodSerial;

  // Find all of the entries within the pay period 
  let validDays = state.monthlyData.AllDays
    .filter(x => x.PayPeriodSerial === payPeriodSerial);

  if (getters.hasFilters) {
    for (let day of validDays) {
      day.ProjectTimes = day.ProjectTimes.filter(x => {
        return (
          x.Project.Client.ID === (state.filters.clientId === 0 ? x.Project.Client.ID : state.filters.clientId) &&
            x.Project.ID === (state.filters.projectId === 0 ? x.Project.ID : state.filters.projectId) &&
            x.ProjectRole.ID === (state.filters.projectRoleId === 0 ? x.ProjectRole.ID : state.filters.projectRoleId) &&
            x.SubProject.ID === (state.filters.subProjectId === 0 ? x.SubProject.ID : state.filters.subProjectId)
        );
      });
    }
  }

  return validDays;
},
```

**Updated Agenda getter (just the change) that Copies the array before the filter**

```
// Find all of the entries within the pay period and make a copy
let validDays = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
  state.monthlyData.AllDays
    .filter(x => x.PayPeriodSerial === payPeriodSerial)
));
```

This is the specific line that was the issue and needed a copy of the array:

`day.ProjectTimes = day.ProjectTimes.filter(x => {`